# doubt about Taylor's series

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand why if $$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^2)$$
we can say that $$\log \cos x=-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^2) $$

Comment: Do you know the Maclaurin series of $\log(1+x)$?

Comment: because $ \ln(1-X)=-X+o(X)$.

Comment: Because near $0$, $\ln(1+u)=u+o(u)$.

Comment: now I see, thanks to all of you

Comment: Actually $\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}2 + O(x^4)$ if I am not mistaken.